# How to keep login in Selenium in Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, cookies

> I was writing a WhatsApp bot and had trouble using selenium
>
> i write this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
# options.add_argument(R"user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

> and get this result

```
py:8: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60230/devtools/browser/2e90af5e-ef48-4fa3-a48d-d065ca78aa36
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\Desktop\Projects\freelance\temp\telgram-search.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 266, in 
__init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 357, in 
start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)  
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in 
execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\mmrah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, 
in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)        
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 95.0.4638.54 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

> what's the problem ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
> ????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Your question is confusing, you refer to Firefox, but you are initiating webdriver for Chrome. The exception clearly states 'This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 95.0.4638.54 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'. You have the incorrect chromedriver, based on the version of your browser use: [ChromeDriver 95.0.4638.17](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.17/chromedriver_win32.zip) from the following website: [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Or

```
options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

webdriver.Chrome doesn't have a param "chrome_options". It has param "options"